# как импортировать массив в react компонент (массив с имена картинок, которые считываю с директории)

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, импорт, export

вот тут я считываю все картинки из директории и формирую из них массив, чтобы передать его в свой компонент и отобразить в select

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');


const PictureObjectCreator = (pathTo) =>  {
  let arrayOut = []
  let allFiles = fs.readdirSync(pathTo)


  for (let i = 0 ; i < allFiles.length ; i+=1){
    allFiles[i] = path.basename(allFiles[i] , '.webp');
    allFiles[i] = allFiles[i].split('_').join(' ')
    arrayOut[i] = {name: allFiles[i] , value: allFiles[i]}
  }

  return arrayOut
}


let gameMode3Path = '../../images/imageForGameMode3'

const gameMode1Select = PictureObjectCreator(gameMode1Path);
const LCEGOList = PictureObjectCreator(gameMode3Path);

exports.LCEGOList = LCEGOList
```

вот тут у меня получилось вывести полученный массив

```
const List = require('./LCDirectoryFileNameReader')
const LCEGOList = List.LCEGOList

console.log(LCEGOList);
```

но при импорте его в браузере выползает вот такая ошибка

Uncaught TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function

подскажите как с ней справится, буду премного благодарен

пробовал импортировать массив в реакт так

```
const List = require('./LCDirectoryFileNameReader')
const LCEGOList = List.LCEGOList
```

и так

```
import { LCEGOList } from "../../LCDitectoryFileNameReader/test";
```

но в любом случае получал ошибку

Comment: Вы наверняка используете какой-то сборщик. (CRA/Webpack, vite или т.п.), они используют прямой импорт картинок (import img from './[filename].jpg'. FS для импорта использовать не надо, т.к. в этом случае картинки в билд импортироваться не будут (да и как это работать на фронте должно?). В целом, во всех сборщиках картинки подключаются +- одинаково, [здесь можно посмотреть как это делается в CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Comment: я хочу сделать сайт, где нужно угадывать персонажа по картинке, а после верного ответа, чтобы появлялся выбор определенного подоброза персонажа. Также изображение менялось раз в день. Поэтому хочу считывать названия всех картинок (они имеют вид название_подоброза_имя_персонажа), обрабатывать название изображения и отправлять в select. Просто по другому не придумал, как автоматически обновлять select (создавать вручную не хочу, картинок примерно 50 штук)

Comment: У вас картинки находятся на бекэенде, а реакт на фронте, как они на фронте подключатся через fs? Используйте картинки как [static файлы](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) или импортируйте, но точно не через fs.

Comment: я понял в чем проблема, спасибо вам за помощь